# Pandas drop unchanging days

Tags: pandas

I need to drop entire days from a dataset when an instrument malfunctions and records duplicate measurements for the entire day. In the example below, I want to remove all rows for 2020-08-27 and keep all rows for 2020-08-28.

```
dates = ['2020-08-27', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28']
values = [100, 100, 100, 200, 201, 200]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "value": values})

         date  value
0  2020-08-27    100
1  2020-08-27    100
2  2020-08-27    100
3  2020-08-28    200
4  2020-08-28    201
5  2020-08-28    200
```

This is code I tried and does not work properly:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["date", "value"], keep=False)

         date  value
4  2020-08-28    201
```

What is the right way to do this?

EDIT:
It turns out, I need this to work with more than one value column. Again in this case I want to keep the 2020-08-28 rows.

```
dates = ['2020-08-27', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-27', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28', '2020-08-28']
values1 = [100, 100, 100, 200, 201, 201, 200]
values2 = [300, 300, 300, 300, 301, 301, 300]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "value1": values1, "value2": values2})

         date  value1  value2
0  2020-08-27     100     300
1  2020-08-27     100     300
2  2020-08-27     100     300
3  2020-08-28     200     300
4  2020-08-28     201     301
5  2020-08-28     201     301
6  2020-08-28     200     300
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `groupby` with `transform` + `nunique` as condition to slice the dataframe:

```
df[df.groupby('date')['value'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
```

Output:

```
         date  value
3  2020-08-28    200
4  2020-08-28    201
5  2020-08-28    200
```

Details:  Group by day and check to see if you have more that one distinct value.

Update to handle multple columns:

```
df[df.groupby('date')[['value1', 'value2']].transform('nunique').ne(1).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
        date  value1  value2
3  2020-08-28     200     300
4  2020-08-28     201     301
5  2020-08-28     201     301
6  2020-08-28     200     300
```

Comment: Nice. Is there a way to extend this to work with more than one value column?

Comment: @steve.  yes, please explain all values in the columns are the same?

Comment: @steve See update, same logic, added a condition that all on a row must equal to 1.